# Combobox change highlight color winRT (metro app)

Tags: windows, colors, combobox, winrt-xaml

I want to change the color of a combobox in a winRT (Windows Store application).

It looks like this. And I would like substitute the purple color.

[image: A weird color]

I tried:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Red</SolidColorBrush>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

This doesn't work because x:Static no more exist in Windows store application and if I use StaticResource, the resource "System.HighlightBrushKey" does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: What is "A weird color"?

Comment: I don't want this purple color, I want to change this color.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like built-in resources names were changed, so now you need to override these brushes:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF4617B4" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF5F37BE" />
```

You can find full list of `ComboBoxItem` brushes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709911.aspx